# Apache VirtualHost wildcards with IPv6

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, ipv6

Using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu, I have the following in ports.conf:

```
Listen XX.73.44.57:80
Listen [2001:XX:0:2c38::39]:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
         Listen XX.73.44.57:443
         Listen [2001:XX:0:2c38::39]:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
         Listen XX.73.44.57:443
         Listen [2001:XX:0:2c38::39]:443
</IfModule>
```

I'd like to have the following in my server configs:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
```

but that doesn't seem to work properly as the hosts don't respond. I've also tried:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80 [::]:80>
```

The following works:

```
<VirtualHost [2001:XX:0:2c38::39]:80 XX.73.44.57:80>
```

but I'd prefer a wildcard. Do I have to give the IP addresses explicitly?

Comment: Do the logs provide any hints as to why `<VirtualHost *:80>` doesn't work? It works for me along with `Listen [::]:80`.

Comment: From what I can tell, it's because I have some hosts with IP addresses specified and other with wildcards. Apache only looks at * if there are no matches for the exact IP address. So for * to work I need to change all the <VirtualHost> lines to use * and listen on all IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a wildcard address (listen on all IP addresses) in a `VirtualHost`, you need your `Listen` directive to be listening on all IP addresses.

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

Comment: I have several IP addresses configured on the host, and only want Apache to listen on some of them. So I take it this means I have to give the IP addresses explicitly in both the Listen and VirtualHost directives? That's annoying as I was hoping to make my virtual hosts configs portable across machines.

Comment: Different machines are going to have the same IP address?

Comment: I have three IP addresses on the physical machine that Apache is running on. I want Apache to bind to one of those addresses on ports 80 and 443. I want another app (not Apache) to bind to port 80 on another one of those addresses, and yet another on port 443 on the third address.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` in ports.conf instead of `Listen 80`. This helped me.